# Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'. Where I'm wrong

Tags: jquery

```
var customerConstant = {
        grdcustomers: "gvcustomers",
        customerPager: "customerPager",
        divRootcustomer: "divRootcustomer",
        mainGridTitile: "Customer Data",
        divShowCustomerSearchPopup: "divShowCustomerSearchPopup",
        divShowPatientSearchPopup: "divShowPatientSearchPopup",
        gridSearchResult: "gridSearchResult",
        divSearchResult: "divSearchResult",
        searchResult: "Search Result",
        searchPager: "searchPager",
        idOfcustomerMainDiv: "idOfcustomerMainDiv",
        Url: {
            getcustomers: "LcmCustomer/Get",
            getcustomerDetails: "LcmCustomer/GetCustomerRecord?customerPatientNumber=",
        }
    };
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Could you show us the code that produces the error?

Comment: getcustomerDetails: "LcmCustomer/GetCustomerRecord?customerPatientNumber=",.. without comma

Comment: Can be caused by the trailing comma at end of `getcustomerDetails` line. Downvoted for obvious reasons.

Comment: Remove the `,` after the last property in the `Url` object. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the last coma:`LcmCustomer/GetCustomerRecord?customerPatientNumber=",`

Answer (score 0):

Remove comma(,) in getcustomerDetails: "LcmCustomer/GetCustomerRecord?customerPatientNumber=", and try:

```
var customerConstant = {
    grdcustomers: "gvcustomers",
    customerPager: "customerPager",
    divRootcustomer: "divRootcustomer",
    mainGridTitile: "Customer Data",
    divShowCustomerSearchPopup: "divShowCustomerSearchPopup",
    divShowPatientSearchPopup: "divShowPatientSearchPopup",
    gridSearchResult: "gridSearchResult",
    divSearchResult: "divSearchResult",
    searchResult: "Search Result",
    searchPager: "searchPager",
    idOfcustomerMainDiv: "idOfcustomerMainDiv",
    Url: {
        getcustomers: "LcmCustomer/Get",
        getcustomerDetails: "LcmCustomer/GetCustomerRecord?customerPatientNumber="
    }
};
```